# Symfony2 slow initialization time on Debian

Tags: php, symfony, webserver

Our site used to be on a shared hosting, now we've moved to a dedicated server with AMD Opteron™ 3280 and 16 GB RAM. The problem is that our system in dev mode is now ways slower than it used to be. On the shared hosting a page load took ~700 ms in dev mode, on this server it takes 7s (10 times more).
I opened the profiler for timing information and found that total time was 6948 ms, initialization was 6255 ms, and the main request was 692.3 ms. For comparison I checked another site which is running on a really bad shared hosting, that had a total time of 1794 ms, but the initialization time was only 190 ms. Why do we have such a long init time? I have symfony2 sites running on many servers (both dedicated and shared) and have never had this problem before.

**System info**

- Debian wheezy
- Php 5.4.4-7
- Apache 2.2.22
- Kernel 3.2.0-3-amd64

Comment: Are you sure you have turned on 'APC' or any other opcode caching?

Comment: is this on the first query or does it become faster on further queries? what file system do you have in the os?

Comment: After deleting the cache, the first query takes ~13s, of which the init time is ~9s, and from the second query on it's ~7s, of which the init time is ~6s(as above). The filesystem is ext3 and we have software raid 1.